# Repairing System Reserved on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running Windows Server Essentials R2 and I have just started getting an error saying:

> One or more server hard drives must be checked for errors
>
> Alert details: The following hard drives need to be checked for
>   errors: System Reserved

I can go to the Disk Manager and find the System Reserved and run a scan, but for this volume "Repair File System Errors" is grayed out.

So, my question is, how do I initiate a repair or rebuild of my System Reserved area?